# Sumif a certain value in column A equals the same value in the same Column

Tags: excel

[There are two columns with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8wSH.png) I looked into the SUMIF() function but none seem to check for matching values within the same column. I cannot figure it out.

I want to sum column A with the same strings in column B. So add all the A, all the B and all the C. But without defining the strings.

Comment: Update this question with a sample of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not wanting to create a list of unique values found in column B first then I think this is all you need.

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$9,B2,$A$2:$A$9)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `SUMIF` to work correctly, you would need a helper column which contain the unique strings, (`Column C`)

[image]

Enter the formula in `Column D` and drag down to get the corresponding sum,

```
=SUMIF(B:B,C2,A:A)
```